# Problem with the "audioplayers" dependency with Flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-virtual-device, audio-player

I want to play a sound when i click on a button, so i used the "audioplayers" dependency:

I imported it into the pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
 sdk: flutter
  //...Other dependencies
  audioplayers: ^0.15.1        
  assets_audio_player: ^2.0.14
```

And this is my PlayerPage.dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class FlipCardPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _FlipCardPage2State createState() => _FlipCardPage2State();
  }

   class _FlipCardPage2State extends State<FlipCardPage2> {
  var firstColor = Color(0xFFD7C26A), secondColor = Color(0xFF451428);

   AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
   AudioPlayerState audioPlayerState = AudioPlayerState.PAUSED;
   AudioCache audioCache;
   String path = "goalceleb.mp3";

   @override
   void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    audioCache = AudioCache(fixedPlayer: audioPlayer);
    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((AudioPlayerState state) {
      setState(() {
    audioPlayerState = state;
    });
   });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
  // TODO: implement dispose
  super.dispose();
  audioPlayer.release();
  audioPlayer.dispose();
  audioCache.clearCache();
 }

  playMusic() async{
   await audioCache.play(path);
 }

 pauseMusic() async{
 await audioPlayer.pause();
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
  
    ),
  ),
  width: double.infinity,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      FlipCard(),
      SizedBox(
        height: 90.0,
      ),
      SliderButton(
          action: () {
            ///Do something here OnSlide
            playMusic();
          },

          
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.power_settings_new,
            color: Colors.red,
            size: 40.0,
            semanticLabel: 'Text to announce in accessibility modes',
          )),
  
    ],
    ),
    );
    }
    }

   //... Other code
   }
```

When I tried to test it with my Android simulator, I got this error message:

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: /home/coach/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org    /assets_audio_player-2.0.15/android/src/main/kotlin/com/github/florent37/assets_audio_player/notification/ImageDownloader.kt: (12, 19): Unresolved reference: FlutterInjector
e: /home/coach/Documents/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/assets_audio_player-2.0.15/android/src/main/kotlin/com/github/florent37/assets_audio_player/notification/ImageDownloader.kt: (61, 53): Unresolved reference: FlutterInjector

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

 BUILD FAILED in 12s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I do some researchs on the net, i executed many commands such as "flutter clean" and "flutter doctor",etc... I don't know if it is a problem related with the Flutter version installed on my Android Studio...

Any idea how to solve this error?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any solution so far here ?

Comment: it's weird, but when i update the flutter sdk and create a new emulator.. it works!

Comment: I also fixed it the same way